# Custom wizard control

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, user-controls

I have to build a custom wizard control in VB.NET for a Windows forms project.  I am not "allowed" to utilize existing wizard controls on the internet due to some obscure logic surrounding copyrights.  I am not "allowed" to use usercontrols in the software.

Does anyone have an idea where I should start?

Comment: You aren't allowed to use usercontrols?  Sounds like that would make for a kludgy wizard at best.

Comment: Step 1: update your resume.  Your organization sounds beyond clueless.  Let me get this straight: they want you to build a custom control... but you're not allowed to use user controls?

Comment: I think Amy means external wizard controls because of trying of license clearance

Comment: @ahockley This is what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my job we implemented a wizard using a panel for each step of the wizard. To facilitate working with the panels, we reduce the size of each panel to a small square and put them side to side in the containing control so when we want to edit a panel, we click on the appropriate square, and put the dock property to fill. When we're done, we put back the dock property to none, and the control goes back to its small square dimensions.

Programmatically, you can do something similar to show the good panel for the current step. When the "Next" button is clicked, hide and undock the previous panel, then show and dock the current panel.

Answer (score 1):

A TabControl is a very convenient control in the designer.  Changing tab pages at runtime is easy too, just set the SelectedIndex or SelectedTab property.  You just need to get rid of the tabs.  Luckily, that's easy.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Build.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
Public Class WizardPages
    Inherits TabControl
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        '--- Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        If m.Msg = &H1328 AndAlso Not DesignMode Then
            m.Result = CType(1, IntPtr)
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```